# FactoryGirl / Bot and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have two factories, a creative and an ad_source_creative with the latter being a lookup table.

If I run:

```
creative = FactoryGirl.create(:creative)
```

I get an error

```
Mysql2::Error: Column 'creative_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `ad_source_creatives` (`ad_source_id`, `creative_id`) VALUES (265, NULL)
```

My two factories are:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :creative do |c|
    # c.association  :advertiser
    ad_source_creative
    advertiser
    ....
```

and

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ad_source_creative do
    ad_source
  end
end
```

and the models have the necessary associations set up. FactoryGirl tends to infer correctly the relationships from the above syntax. Is this correct? Or am I making some syntax error (very likely)?

#### edit #1 - models

```
class AdSourceCreative < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ad_source
  belongs_to :creative  
  ...
end


class Creative < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ad_source_creative
  ...
end
```

Comment: What's the association b/w `creative` and `ad_source_creative`?

Comment: It would be handy to see the relationships between the two models, could you include them in the question?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna updated with models. If I add a creative to the ad_source_factory, it generates an infinite loop

Comment: Why don't you try something like not defining the association in the factories altogether and see when you build the objects, you associate them ? something like this `let(:creative)  { build :creative }`
   `let(:ad_source_creative) { build :ad_source_creative, creative: creative }`